# Is it possible to share constant variable which its value receive from the Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I'm created a cron job with `Cron` module. Currently, I declared that **cron job** in `crawler.js` file and its **cron rules** in `settings.js` file just like below:

File `settings.js`:

```js
const cronCrawlItemsRule = '0 */10 * * * *'

module.exports = { cronCrawlItemsRule  }
```

File `crawler.js`:

```js
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
connectDB();

const { cronCrawlItemsRule } = require './settings.js';

const crawlItems = new CronJob(cronCrawlItemsRule, async function() {
  // do stuff here and save to DB that connected above.
})
```

**Problem:** *I want to save **cron rules to DB**, then whenever I start the server, get those **cron rules** and the **crons** will run follow that **rules**.* Remind that those rules will be got **once** the server is started.

Is it possible to do this? I've tried like below:

```js
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
connectDB();

const { cronCrawlItemsRule } = require './settings.js';

(async() => {
  const rule = (await Config.findOne({...}))?._doc.value || cronCrawlItemsRule; // <- here
  const crawlItems = new CronJob(rule, async function() { // <- and here
    // do stuff here and save to DB that connected above.
})
})()
```

but I have to get those rules from DB again whenever I need them in other files.

*Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To who is stuck at the same problem. After spending few days, I figured out the solution.

- In `settings.js` file, exports a function to fetch settings from DB like below, it means that you will exports variable named `cronCrawlItemsRule` whenever `fetchSettingFromDb` function get called:

```js
const setting1 = '...';
const setting2 = '...';
const fetchSettingFromDb = async () => {
  module.exports.cronCrawlItemsRule = (await Config.findOne({...}))?._doc.value || '0 */10 * * * *';
}


module.exports = { setting1, setting2, fecthSettingFromDb }
```

- Make sure your app is connected to DB by put `await` before `connectDb` function in the `crawler.js` file.

```js
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

// Because this "cronCrawlItemsRule" variable is not declared nor exported in settings.js file.
// Required it like below can raise error.
// const { cronCrawlItemsRule } = require './settings.js' // DON'T USE THIS
const settings = require './settings.js'; //<= USE THIS

// But which variable exported from the begin in settings.js file can be required as usual
const { setting1, setting2, fetchSettingFromDb } = require('./settings');

(async () => {
  await connectDB();
  
  await fecthSettingFromDb();
  // It works thanks to settings.cronCrawlItemsRule;
  const crawlItems = new CronJob(settings.cronCrawlItemsRule, async function() {
    // do stuff here and save to DB that connected above.
})
})()
```